# Response time is very slow in iPhone device when saving or loading images

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimage

I try my app in the simulator and all goes fine but when I try it on the device the response time until bringing the data is very slow..what can I do and what is the reason?

I realized that the problem is that in my entity I have photo field that store image in binary data and when I save image to core data or pull the image to show in table view its takes a lot of time.

Code for saving image as `NSData`:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageView.image);
```

Code for bringing image from core data:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[recipe valueForKey:@"image"]];
```

and this is slowing my loading and saving to core data. What is the solution for saving and loading images from Core Data?

Comment: Can you add some code? Show your NSFetchRequest at least.

Comment: It would be good to run Instruments and see where the bottleneck is. Those lines of code compress/decompress PNG. If your images are large, that could be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

The best advices I can give are the following

- when you save a context do it in a background thread. You should follow thread confinement rules for `NSManagedObjectContext`. You can also rely on new Core Data API if you targets iOS 5 devices.
- use *Allows External Storage* flag.

> If you specify that the value of a managed object attribute may be
>   stored as an external record, Core Data heuristically decides on a
>   per-value basis whether it should save the data directly in the
>   database or store a URI to a separate file that it manages for you.

[image]

- fetch and retrieve the image representation in a background thread. Once done, grab the main thread and set the image (e.g. [Using Grand Central Dispatch for Asynchronous Table View Cells](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/)).

I would try the first two steps before going to the third one.

Comment: I found my problem...because I saved the image as PNG and the image are large its take time to load and save them to core data.I compress the image to JPAG using: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 0.3) and its works fine.

Comment: Im using Xcode 5.1 and the second option you advice me is not shown on my image attribute.Can i do it with other way in Xcode 5.1?